# how to scrape data from this site using beautifullsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import bs4
html_page = requests.get(
    'https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan')
html_page.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, features='lxml')
h = soup.find('div','ProductList')
print(h)
```

but it's returning null object. how to get prices of the product from this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price is placed in div with class "ActualPrice". To get all such div-elements you may use:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='ActualPrice')
```

To get prices and product details you may do something like this:

```
import requests
import bs4
html_page = requests.get(
    'https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan')
html_page.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, features='lxml')
products = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-box')
for product in products[:3]: #for the first 3 products
    product_name = product.find('h5', class_='ProductDetails')
    print(product_name.text)
    product_price = product.find('div', class_='ActualPrice')
    print(product_price.text)

#Output
Apple iPhone XS (4G, 64GB, Gold) - PTA Approved.
Rs 131,999
Apple iPhone XS Max (4G, 256GB Gold) - PTA Approved
Rs 154,999
Oppo A5 2020 Dual Sim (4G, 4GB RAM, 128Gb ROM, Mirror Black) With 1 Year Official Warranty 
Rs 31,599
```

When you scroll down JS from the page generates requests with URL that looks like: 
https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan?page=1&AjaxRequest=1.

To get all phones from this page you can just iterate through all of them:

```
import requests
import bs4
page_number = 1
more_products = True
while more_products:
    html_page = requests.get(
        'https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan?page={}&AjaxRequest=1'.format(page_number))
    html_page.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, features='lxml')
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-box')
    if not products:
        more_products = False
    for product in products[0]: #for the first product in every request
        product_name = product.find('h5', class_='ProductDetails')
        print(product_name.text)
        product_price = product.find('div', class_='ActualPrice')
        print(product_price.text)
    page_number += 1
```

Comment: what if i wanna get all phone numbers ?because when i scroll down more products appear

Comment: Add it to my answer